# PHP rerouting temporarily store the previous output

Tags: php, reroute

I have output from a page (`Uploader.php`). Now i go to some other page and have a button on that page to reroute to this page (`Uploader.php`). I want the input of the page to be seen rather than reprocessing the page.

Comment: Sorry I can't really understand the question

Comment: http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#writewell

Comment: Reword "I want the input of the page to be seen rather than reprocessing the page." It's not clear what is meant by this.

Comment: What i meant is this 1) from the page Index.php i am routed to unpoader.php
2) In this page, Uploader.php some processing is done and then a output is displayed with some buttons and table
3) On pressing any of the buttons i am rerouted to another page- Overflow.php
4) Now i want to be rerouted to Uploader.php- But this time there should be no processing of the page as earlier- what i mean is that- the prevous output having tables and those buttons should be displyed.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can infer of the question you want to have a form that allows the user to upload whatever information. After they submit, you want to either show a 'review' page (for the user to confirm or deny the action to be performed), or a 'results' page to review what was performed/uploaded/input.

For easy of programming I would have two PHP files, Uploader.php and Uploader-View.php
Uploader.php would have your form and post to whatever form action script you have for processing it. The action script could then redirect to Uploader-View.php with the form values placed in the page as text, rather than as form fields.
If you wanted to re-use Uploader.php you could have some variable to determine the state of the workflow and decide whether to show form fields or variable values.